# Is it possible to share links with another Pinboard user?

Tags: sharing, bookmarks, delicious, pinboard

I want to be able to bookmark links for my wife and have her see them in [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in/) somehow.  When we used [Delicious](http://delicious.com), I could tag a link with `for:my-wifes-account` and have it appear in her inbox.